# How to use variables in terminal prompt (bash) to modify files' names?

Tags: bash, terminal, command-prompt

I'd like to run a command like this:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full  ./program < speed-01.in
```

I've got a few tests like this ending with different suffix like `-02`, `-03` and so on.

Instead of writting a bash script I wanted to run these tests one by one while chaning only the last digit like this:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full  ./program < speed-0${A}.in ${A}=1
```

However, it seems like it isn't the proper way to introduce variables in this case.

My question is: **how can I use a variable in such case? Is it even possible to write in such way that the whole idea does have any sense?**

Comment: Why iterate over numbers, as opposed to looking at which files exist on the filesystem?

Comment: @RC, not without a `;` or newline.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes I was trying on a shell and saw that. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @RC. ...in terms of *why* it works that way, `var=val somecommand` runs `command` with `var` exported in the environment with the value `val` (only for that one command, removing it after), but doesn't have that set during expansions in setting up `somecommand`.

Comment: ok, so there is no way to use variables in the prompt like this: `somecommand var=val` (inversing the whole prompt)?

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski, putting `var=val` after the command passes `var=val` as a string to the command. I wouldn't say that there's *no way* to make that work -- you could make `somecommand` a function that interprets those arguments -- but it'd be kinda' silly.

Comment: Why do you want it at the end? Is that just ease-of-typing? If so, see my recent edit.

Comment: Yeah, it was about the ease of typing and not running all the speed tests at once. Thank you! May I ask for one more clarification? How can I write this line: `valgrind --leak-check=full ./program <"speed-${num}.in"` if the *.in files are in another folder?

Comment: `<"/path/to/directory/with/speed-${num}.in"`. Incidentally, "folder" is Windows parlance; UNIX folks tend to object to it a bit.

Comment: (BTW, `speed-$num.in` is perfectly correct here too; the curly braces are optional when you don't need to do any fancy parameter expansions and your variable name isn't followed by characters which could also be legally part of the name; periods aren't legal in shell variable names, so the curly braces are optional here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for f in speed-*.in; do
  valgrind --leak-check=full  ./program <"$f"
done
```

...or, if you *really* want to count numbers for some reason...

```
for ((a=0; a<9; a++)); do
  printf -v num '%02d' "$a" # add a leading 0 only if number is less than 10
  valgrind --leak-check=full ./program <"speed-${num}.in"
done
```

---

Now, if you want to make it easy to run this manually with different values, just define a function:

```
leakcheck() {
  local num
  printf -v num '%02d' "$1"
  valgrind --leak-check=full ./program <"speed-${num}.in"
}
```

...then you can run...

```
leakcheck 1
leakcheck 2
...
```

Comment: An alternative for loop which ditches the printf entirely would be like "for num in {00..09}; do ...."

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using your example is

```
A=1
valgrind --leak-check=full  ./program < speed-0$((A++))
```

Then, repeat the last line up to nine more times.

This becomes more complicated if you want 01..12, for example.

Comment: ...though code that correctly handles 01...12 is something I've demonstrated, with the printf trick, so it should be easy to adapt.